# But they cannot agree on who/whom that should be

Tags: who-whom

The sentence is from The Economist.

## Original sentence

But they cannot agree on ***who*** that should be.

## My question

Would it be ***whom***, if the sentence only were: "But they cannot agree on ***whom***."?

I'm fully aware of the who/whom rules regarding prepostions. Is this a special case because "who" belongs to "who that should be"?

Comment: *In principle* it should probably be ***whom*** (on the grounds that a possible resolution is *It should be **him***, not ***he***). But ***whom*** is hopelessly old-fashioned today (except after ***to***, in ***To whom** am I speaking?* on the phone - but we often avoid that one by asking ***Who** am I speaking **to**?,* so it *doesn't* come immediately after the preposition). So just go with ***who*** and forget about the ***who / whom*** distinction, same as most native speakers.

Comment: ...note that if you remove ***that should be*** you could make a case for either ***who*** or ***whom***. That's because what you're left with *might* occur in a context like *They cannot agree on **who should do it*** (where a possible resolution is ***He** should do it*, not ***Him***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - okay, my thanks. I have asked this question because I, as you have said, thought that it possibly should be "whom" in the original sentence. But I didn't dare to ask. I mean, it is The Economist. You get me.

Comment: There are several instances of [*agree on **who** that should be*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22agree+on+who+that+should+be%22) in Google Books, but there;s only *one* instance of [*agree on **whom** that should be*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22agree+on+whom+that+should+be%22) Feasibly some benighted test-setter might still be looking for ***whom*** in a TEFL test, but actual native speakers left this one behind decades ago. *Except* when it follows immediately after preposition ***to***, in which case possibly *most* of us still use ***whom*** (or rephrase! :)

Comment: One might be a little more tolerant of **whom**, as in **from whom did you get it** (comes naturally to me) but I'm probably a bit older than fumblefingers and likely to be categorised as hopelessly old fashioned.

Comment: @RonaldSole: Yes - probably quite a few people would use ***whom*** in your context. But it's still a context where ***who / whom*** immediately follows the preposition (*and* as with ***Who** am I speaking **to**?*, we often just rephrase to avoid "awkwardness"). OP's context does actually have ***on*** before ***who / whom***, but it's a very "weak" preposition usage that many if not most of us wouldn't even include in the utterance anyway (it reads fine with no preposition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle the text should probably use ***whom*** (on the grounds that a possible resolution is *It should be **him***, not ***he***).

But ***whom*** is hopelessly old-fashioned today (except after ***to***, in ***To whom** am I speaking?* on the phone - but we often avoid that one by asking ***Who** am I speaking **to**?*, so it doesn't come immediately after the preposition).

So the easy answer is just go with ***who*** and forget about the ***who / whom*** distinction, same as most native speakers (different morphology for verb subject and object is primarily a feature of *Latin*, not English).

As commented, some people are happy with (or prefer) ***From whom** did you get it?* Which is again a context where the immediately preceding term is a preposition - unless we rephrase to put it at the end, as ***Who** did you get it **from**?*

It may be worth noting that OP's cited example features a very "weak" preposition ***on***. I say "weak" because we can easily just remove it entirely without affecting anything else (except that if there's no preposition at all before ***who / whom***, we're *much* more likely to use the modern simpler style.